# Cómo estructurar un Cron para que ejecute un store procedure mysql cada día?

Tags: mysql, hosting, cron, crontab

quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar, tengo un store procedure en mysql subido a un hosting había creado un evento (mysql) para que ejecutara todos los días el store procedure, el detalle es que local me funciona, pero en el hosting no, contactandome con mi proveedor me mencionó que los eventos de la base de datos están desactivados, entonces me ofreció hacerlos a traves de un cron, pero nunca he hecho uno y he buscado información, pero no encuentro algo que realmente me ayude.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En ese caso tendrías que programar un script de consola, php que llame a la SP que has programado y luego programar un cron job que ejecute ese archivo una vez al día.

Comment: @A.Cedano, podrías darme detalles, por ejemplo que es lo que iría realmente en el script de consola? solo la conexión a la bd y la llamada al sp? o que más? o si no tendrás algun link donde pueda guiarme para toda esta información? Gracias

Comment: [Mira aquí un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196785/5587982). Sería simplemente crear un archivo con extensión `.ssh` con un contenido parecido a ese (en vez de la instrucción `DELETE` que hay ahí debes poner una llamada a tu SP). Luego, cuando programes el cron, tienes que llamar al archivo `.ssh` (poniendo la ruta correcta para bash en tu entorno), e indicando la frecuencia del cron y listo. Aunque debo decir que el estilo del script, poniendo a mano el password de mysql no me gusta, es mejor usar un archivo de configuración, pero ese es otro asunto.

Comment: @A.Cedano, hice lo que me dijiste, pero no funciona, no se por qué, esto son los datos mysql --user=miusuario --password=micontraseña --database=mibd --execute="call recalcula_credito();" y está en la raiz de mi sistema. no sé, creo que me tocará hacerlo manual antes de poder solucionar totalmente esto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes escribir un script que ejecute la llamada a tu procedimiento almacenado y luego programar un Cron Job que llame a ese script.

Para que esto funcione es importante que pongas las rutas correctas en todos los casos y, por supuesto, que tu procedimiento almacenado no sea erróneo.

Dado que es muy peligroso escribir la constraseña en la consola (la misma podría quedar registrada en los logs) usaremos un archivo de configuración, para no exponer la contraseña.

Veamos el script:

#### `recalcula_credito.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=~/.credentials/.mysql.cnf --execute="call recalcula_credito();"
```

Dos cosas:

1. La ruta de mysql, en mi caso, es `/usr/bin/mysql`, si en tu caso es otra, debes cambiar eso.
2. Si observas, para la conexión, he indicado un archivo que se llama `.mysql.cnf` y que está en una carpeta oculta llamada `.credentials` ubicada en el directorio principal. El contenido de este archivo es más o menos este:

   #### `.credentials/.mysql.cnf`

   ```
   [client]
       host     = localhost
       user     = AQUI_TU_USUARIO_SIN_COMILLAS
       password = "AQUI_TU_PASSWORD_ENTRE_COMILLAS"
       database = AQUI_TU_BASE_DE_DATOS_SIN_COMILLAS
   ```

   Como ya dije antes, el propósito de este archivo es **no exponer tu constraseña**. La conexión usará este archivo, en vez de recibirla por escrito, lo cual podría provocar que se guarden en eventuales logs.

Ahora sólo tienes que programar un Cron Job que llame a tu archivo `recalcula_credito.sh`. Cuando escribas el Cron, debes indicarle quizá la ruta de bash, así como la ruta correcta de tu script. Si no funciona, será sin duda un problema de rutas.

Para probar el script, lo puedes hacer desde consola con algo como esto:

```
sh recalcula_credito.sh
```

Ahí deberás ver en consola lo que trae tu SP, si trae algo claro y si hay algún error, te dirá qué error es.

Comment: esos datos los tiene un archivo que utilizo en mi framework, lo vinculo? te pregunto, porque yo uso laravel para programar y pues es un servidor compartido, entonces la ruta no sabría cual es exactamente

Comment: @MauEspaña Laravel es simplemente un framework, así que esto no tiene nada que ver con Laravel, estamos hablando de un nivel más bajo de programación, pues esto trabajará directamente en la consola, sin intermediarios como Laravel u otros, es más, ni siquiera con PHP. Supongo que tienes acceso de algún modo a tu servidor ¿no? Mediante la misma consola, mediante un cliente SFTP, mediante cPanel, u otro. Con eso, explorando los directorios, podrás ver dónde está cada cosa.

Comment: si es que no tengo acceso, mi proveedor en su hosting usa incluso cwp web panel, no el famoso cpanel y lastimosamente no tiene ni siquiera habilitados los eventos de mysql, sino no habría problema y no puedo realmente ver en qué ruta se encuentra el archivo conf, podría asumir que es ese, ya que creo que esa es la ruta default, pero no serviría

Comment: Ummm no creo, aunque sea un hosting compartido deberías tener acceso con tu usuario y contraseña, incluso desde la consola de tu propio ordenador ... así de simple ... aunque podría ser peligroso para tus datos en ese servidor si no extremas precauciones. Si vas a interactuar mucho con los archivos podrías configurar a posteriori un tunel entre tu ordenador y el servidor con llaves públicas / privadas. Yo tengo un hosting compartido y accedo de ese modo, porque interactúo mucho a ese nivel con la BD sobre todo... Pero dejemos eso ahora. ¿A ese `cwp web panel` sí puedes acceder?